# Jackcess, loop with multiple matching rows very slow,

Tags: java, ms-access, jackcess

I execute this my code and i don't understant why elapsed time is very high for loop.

There are two loops. First loop on Invoices table and the seconde loop on InvoicesLignes table.

InvoicesLignes table has a index "Code", it's the "foreign-key" of Invoice. In database Access, there is a relation between Invoices and InvoicesLines, but the foreign-key is not defined and i can't use the Joiner class. I can't modify Database.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;

class MultipleLoop {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File jfile = new File("/project/database.mdb");

    Date start_date= new Date("2013/01/01");
    Date end_date= new Date("2013/12/31");

    try {

        Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(jfile);

        Table invoices = db.getTable("Invoices");
        Table invoices_lignes = db.getTable("InvoiceLignes");

        Cursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(invoices_lignes.getIndex("Code"));

        for(Row invoice : invoices) {

          if ((start_date.before((Date)invoice.get("Date")) 
                    || start_date.equals((Date)invoice.get("Date"))) 
              &&  
              (end_date.after((Date)invoice.get("Date")) 
                    || end_date.equals((Date)invoice.get("Date")) )) {

          System.out.println(String.format("Invoice id : '%s' time : '%s'", 
                             invoice.get("Code"),
                             System.currentTimeMillis( ) ));

          long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );

          for (Row invoice_ligne : cursor.newIterable().addMatchPattern("Code",
                                                           invoice.get("Code"))) 
          {
              System.out.println(String.format("Loop time : '%s'", 
                                 System.currentTimeMillis( )));
          }

          long end = System.currentTimeMillis( );

          System.out.println(String.format("\n\nEnd loop time : '%s'", 
                             System.currentTimeMillis( )));
          long diff = end - start;

          System.out.println(String.format("Loop elapsed time : '%s' ms\n\n", 
                             diff ));

          }

        }

       } catch (IOException e) {
      //} catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
      }

    }
}
```

and my log is

```
Invoice id : '19901/79018' time : '1411043140236' 
Loop time : '1411043140237'
Loop time : '1411043140237'
Loop time : '1411043140237'
Loop time : '1411043140237'


End loop time : '1411043141335'
Loop elapsed time : '1098' ms


 Invoice id : '138901/909719' time : '1411043141335'
 Loop time : '1411043141336'
 Loop time : '1411043141336'


 End loop time : '1411043142418'
 Loop elapsed time : '1083' ms


 Invoice id : '1309091/729090' time : '1411043142419'
 Loop time : '1411043142419'
 Loop time : '1411043142419'


 End loop time : '1411043143515'
 Loop elapsed time : '1096' ms
```

I don't understand why elapsed time is very high for loop

Thank for your help

Comment: Basically, as @GordThompson wrote, if you don't have an index on the search column, then you have to do a full table scan for every find.  if you have enough memory in your jvm, you could build your own lookup table.

Comment: I use index ["Code"]... i updated my code and my log. exemple : invoice '19901/79018', no dealy to find InvoiceLignes, but there is delay at the end of the loop.

Comment: hmm, i wonder if there is a bug in the index lookups where it's not fast failing at the end of the matching range.

Comment: Related: [Bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/jackcess/bugs/109/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are still effectively scanning the whole [InvoicesLignes] table for each iteration of the outer [Invoices] loop. Your approach ...

```java
Table invoices = db_opened.getTable("Invoices");
Table invoices_lignes = db_opened.getTable("InvoicesLignes");
Cursor cursor = CursorBuilder.createCursor(invoices_lignes.getIndex("Code"));

for (Row row : invoices) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );
    System.out.println(String.format("Invoice : '%s'", start));

    for (Row crow : cursor.newIterable().addMatchPattern("Code", row.get("Code"))) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis( )));
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis( );
    System.out.println(String.format("End loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis( )));
    long diff = end - start;
    System.out.println(String.format("Loop elapsed time : '%s' ms", diff ));
}
```

... produces:

```
Invoice : '1411041092492'
Loop : '1411041092527'
Loop : '1411041092528'
Loop : '1411041092529'
End loop : '1411041094440'
Loop elapsed time : '1948' ms
Invoice : '1411041094442'
Loop : '1411041094443'
Loop : '1411041094444'
End loop : '1411041095882'
Loop elapsed time : '1440' ms
```

However, this variation ...

```java
Table invoices = db_opened.getTable("Invoices");
Table invoices_lignes = db_opened.getTable("InvoicesLignes");

for (Row row : invoices) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );
    System.out.println(String.format("Invoice : '%s'", start));

    IndexCursor cursor = new CursorBuilder(invoices_lignes)
            .setIndexByName("Code")
            .setSpecificEntry(row.get("Code"))
            .toIndexCursor();
    for (Row crow : cursor) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis( )));
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis( );
    System.out.println(String.format("End loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis( )));
    long diff = end - start;
    System.out.println(String.format("Loop elapsed time : '%s' ms", diff ));
}
```

... produces:

```
Invoice : '1411041030007'
Loop : '1411041030060'
Loop : '1411041030062'
Loop : '1411041030063'
End loop : '1411041030063'
Loop elapsed time : '56' ms
Invoice : '1411041030067'
Loop : '1411041030069'
Loop : '1411041030070'
End loop : '1411041030071'
Loop elapsed time : '4' ms
```

Also, have you considered using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html)? The corresponding UCanAccess code ...

```java
String dbFileSpec = "C:/Users/Gord/Desktop/InvoiceTest.mdb";
try (Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileSpec)) {
    PreparedStatement psLignes = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM InvoicesLignes WHERE Code=?");
    Statement sInv = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsInv = sInv.executeQuery("SELECT Code FROM Invoices");
    while (rsInv.next()) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );
        System.out.println(String.format("Invoice : '%s'", start));

        psLignes.setString(1, rsInv.getString("Code"));
        ResultSet rsLignes = psLignes.executeQuery();
        while (rsLignes.next()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis()));
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis( );
        System.out.println(String.format("End loop : '%s'", System.currentTimeMillis( )));
        long diff = end - start;
        System.out.println(String.format("Loop elapsed time : '%s' ms", diff ));
    }
    conn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

... produces:

```
Invoice : '1411041417462'
Loop : '1411041417478'
Loop : '1411041417478'
Loop : '1411041417479'
End loop : '1411041417479'
Loop elapsed time : '17' ms
Invoice : '1411041417482'
Loop : '1411041417483'
Loop : '1411041417483'
End loop : '1411041417483'
Loop elapsed time : '1' ms
```

UCanAccess can increase the startup time of the Java application because it copies the Access data into an hsqldb "mirror" database (in-memory by default), but once loaded it is very fast and we can use regular SQL instead of working directly with the Jackcess API.

For more information on UCanAccess see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: Thank Gord, i updated my code. I don't understand : scanning the whole [InvoicesLignes] table, i use index ["Code"]. In the new log we can see the Invoice '19901/79018' with measure point '1411043140236' and after, the measure points of InvoicesLignes, there is no delay. But at end of the loop there is delay '1097 ms' why, i don't...

Comment: I can't use UCanAccess, because the database is updating by another application in the same time, it's not compatible the "mirror" of hsqldb. And the database is tall,  > 1Go.

Comment: Your version is all right, thank Gord. And the winner is... Jackcess ! 15.2 secondes for ODBC and 6.1 secondes for Jackcess. In French : Il n'y a pas photo !